# setHomeAsUpIndicator is not take effect when use setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)

Tags: android

I want to change ActionBar Indicator（the left arrow） and don't want to display the logo
so i setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false) to make the logo is invisiable,
and setHomeAsUpIndicator(my image) to change the indicator,
but it doesn't work

Comment: What does "out doesn't work" mean? What happens?

Comment: if setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true), i can replace the image;
else setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false), i can't replace the image.....

Answer (score 3):

One way is to not call `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)`. Instead use `findViewById()` to get the home View, and directly set it to `GONE`.

```
View homeView = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
homeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: When using support v7 library revision 21 it just doesn't work - `findViewById(android.R.id.home)` always returns null as I can see

Comment: @sberezin Apologies. In reviewing my inbox, I just realized I'd not seen your message. When using that support library, you might be using the `Toolbar` class, instead of an `ActionBar`. I would direct you to [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279953/get-reference-to-drawer-toggle-in-support-actionbar/28280347#28280347) for a general sense of what's happening. I hope it'll give you an idea of how to proceed in your circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this in your `Manifest.xml` file

`android:logo=@null` or `android:icon=@null`