# Get reference to drawer toggle in support actionbar

Tags: android, android-support-library

I use [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) library for app tutorial. I need to get a reference to Navigation Drawer toggle button(aka "burger button"):

[image]

I use Toolbar as Actionbar, and I have no idea how to get this button. Usually to toggle drawer I use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            toggleDrawer(Gravity.START);
        }
}
```

But when I use Device Monitor to make snapshot of the screen, there's no view with id "home".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That is what's called the navigation button, and it's actually an `ImageButton` nested inside the `Toolbar`. Unfortunately, there is no public method or field by which to get reference to it, so we have to go roundabout.

There are several different approaches to this, of varying degrees of effectiveness and prudence. Take your pick.

#### Navigation `OnClickListener`

If this hadn't occurred to you yet, I would point out the that `View` parameter in the navigation `OnClickListener`'s method will be the navigation button itself. If you're setting that listener yourself, and you don't actually need access to the button until the user clicks it, there's nothing special you need to do, really.

- **Java**

  ```java
  toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> {
      ImageButton navigationButton = (ImageButton) v;
      …
  });
  ```
- **Kotlin**

  ```kotlin
  toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
      val navigationButton = it as ImageButton
      …
  }
  ```

#### Iterative

If you have control over it and are able to set the toggle first thing, then directly afterward the navigation button should be the first (and possibly only) `ImageButton` child of the `Toolbar`. If you're confident that it is, then this is probably the most straightforward of the remaining methods.

- **Java**

  ```java
  static ImageButton getNavigationButton(Toolbar toolbar) {
      for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); ++i) {
          final View child = toolbar.getChildAt(i);
          if (child instanceof ImageButton) {
              return (ImageButton) child;
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
  ```
- **Kotlin**

  ```kotlin
  import androidx.core.view.children

  val Toolbar.navigationButton: ImageButton?
      get() = children.firstOrNull { it is ImageButton } as ImageButton?
  ```

#### Reflective

This method has the advantage of absolute certainty. However, it is reflection, so ya know, whatever your thoughts are on that.

- **Java**

  ```java
  static ImageButton getNavigationButton(Toolbar toolbar) {
      try {
          final Field mNavButtonView =
                  Toolbar.class.getDeclaredField("mNavButtonView");
          mNavButtonView.setAccessible(true);
          return (ImageButton) mNavButtonView.get(toolbar);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```
- **Kotlin**

  ```kotlin
  val Toolbar.navigationButton: ImageButton?
      get() = try {
          Toolbar::class.java
              .getDeclaredField("mNavButtonView").apply {
                  isAccessible = true
              }.get(this) as ImageButton?
      } catch (e: Exception) {
          null
      }
  ```

#### Find by Content Description

This is the first of several methods that accomplish the task by setting some property of the navigation button with a special value. This one temporarily sets its content description to a unique value, and utilizes the `ViewGroup#findViewsWithText()` method to look for it before restoring the original description.

This and the **Find by Tag** example both use this string resource, which can be whatever unique value you like, really:

```xml
<string name="nav_button_locator">ToolbarNavigationButtonLocator</string>
```

- **Java**

  ```java
  static ImageButton getNavigationButton(Toolbar toolbar) {
      final CharSequence originalDescription =
              toolbar.getNavigationContentDescription();
      final CharSequence locator =
              toolbar.getResources()
                      .getText(R.string.nav_button_locator);
      toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(locator);
      final ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<>();
      toolbar.findViewsWithText(
              views,
              locator,
              View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
      toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(originalDescription);
      for (View view : views) {
          if (view instanceof ImageButton) {
              return (ImageButton) view;
          }
      }
      return null;
  }
  ```
- **Kotlin**

  ```kotlin
  val Toolbar.navigationButton: ImageButton?
      get() {
          val originalDescription = navigationContentDescription
          val locator =
              resources.getText(R.string.nav_button_locator)
          navigationContentDescription = locator
          val views = ArrayList<View>()
          findViewsWithText(
              views,
              locator,
              View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION
          )
          navigationContentDescription = originalDescription
          return views.firstOrNull { it is ImageButton } as ImageButton?
      }
  ```

#### Find by Tag

This method takes advantage of being able to style the navigation button through the `toolbarNavigationButtonStyle` theme attribute. In the specified style, we set the `android:tag` attribute to our unique locator string, and use the `View#findViewWithTag()` method to grab it at runtime.

```xml
<style name="Theme.YourApp" parent="...">
    ...
    <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.Navigation</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.Button.Navigation" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
    <item name="android:tag">@string/nav_button_locator</item>
</style>
```

- **Java**

  ```java
  static ImageButton getNavigationButton(Toolbar toolbar) {
      final CharSequence tag =
          toolbar.getResources().getText(R.string.nav_button_locator);
      return toolbar.findViewWithTag(tag);
  }
  ```
- **Kotlin**

  ```kotlin
  val Toolbar.navigationButton: ImageButton?
      get() = findViewWithTag(resources.getText(R.string.nav_button_locator))
  ```

#### Find by ID

Using the same styling technique as the tag method, we can instead set the `android:id` attribute, and possibly get this working with the familiar `findViewById()` functionality. However, if they ever do set an ID on that button – even if just for internal use – this will very likely fail or break something in the `Toolbar`.

We first define an ID to assign the button:

```xml
<item name="navigation_button" type="id" />
```

Then alter the previous theme setup to set the ID rather than the tag:

```xml
<style name="Theme.YourApp" parent="...">
    ...
    <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.Button.Navigation</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.App.Button.Navigation" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
    <item name="android:id">@id/navigation_button</item>
</style>
```

Just for completeness' sake:

- **Java**

  ```java
  static ImageButton getNavigationButton(Toolbar toolbar) {
      return toolbar.findViewById(R.id.navigation_button);
  }
  ```
- **Kotlin**

  ```kotlin
  val Toolbar.navigationButton: ImageButton?
      get() = findViewById(R.id.navigation_button)
  ```

#### Drawable Callback

This one takes advantage of the fact that an `ImageButton` will set itself as its source `Drawable`'s `Callback`. We create a throwaway `Drawable` to temporarily set as the navigation icon, check if the `Callback` object is our `ImageButton`, and restore the original icon. We set our own `Drawable` unconditionally here, rather than fiddling with checking for an existing one first.

- **Java**

  ```java
  static ImageButton getNavigationButton(Toolbar toolbar) {
      final Drawable originalIcon = toolbar.getNavigationIcon();
      final ColorDrawable temporaryDrawable = new ColorDrawable(0);
      toolbar.setNavigationIcon(temporaryDrawable);
      Object callback = temporaryDrawable.getCallback();
      toolbar.setNavigationIcon(originalIcon);
      if (callback instanceof ImageButton) {
          return (ImageButton) callback;
      }
      else {
          return null;
      }
  }
  ```
- **Kotlin**

  ```kotlin
  val Toolbar.navigationButton: ImageButton?
      get() {
          val originalIcon: Drawable? = navigationIcon
          val temporaryDrawable = ColorDrawable(0)
          navigationIcon = temporaryDrawable
          val callback: Any? = temporaryDrawable.callback
          navigationIcon = originalIcon
          return callback as? ImageButton
      }
  ```

---

##### Notes:

- The navigation button is instantiated dynamically on demand. This means that something must have set some navigation button property before you can find it, whether that something is a theme setting or some code of your own. This isn't a problem for the **Find by Content Description** and **Drawable Callback** options, as they begin by setting such a property. For the other methods, however, you might need to take care with your timing.
- Previous revisions of this answer assumed that some setups might be using the `Toolbar`'s logo for the toggle, in lieu of the navigation button. This is highly unlikely, so its mention is moved to this footnote, if only to retain the knowledge somewhere accessible.

  - The **Navigation `OnClickListener`** option is not workable with the logo `View`.
  - The logo is an `ImageView`, and the same advice in the **Iterative** option applies.
  - The field name for the `View` is `mLogoView`, and the **Reflective** method can be altered to look for that.
  - The `Toolbar` class offers the `setLogoDescription()` method, which can be used with the **Find by Content Description** method to find the logo instead.
  - There is also the `setLogo()` method to utilize with the **Drawable Callback** technique.
  - The **Find by Tag** option is not workable with the logo `View`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Xml file just add a view in leftmost of toolbar/Layout, and use this view in your showcase target

Comment: Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.