# Find title textview in toolbar after replacing the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, android-titlebar

The material scrolling activity can display title in the Coordinator-layout.

[image]

We can get it by replacing `actionbar` with a `toolbar` by:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And the xml:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

If I add textView in the toolbar, i find it doesnot have zoom effect like the default one.

My question is: How can I find this title `textview` so that I can modify it (change font/color/...) ?

Comment: Why don't you just put your own `TextView` in the `Toolbar` for the title? `Toolbar` is a `ViewGroup`.

Comment: I find it does not have the zoom (paralax) effect like the default one.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I've not done enough with `CoordinatorLayout` to know how to setup that behavior for your own, but you could get a reference to the title `TextView` in a manner similar to what's described in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28280347). If you use the reflective method, the title `TextView`'s field name is `"mTitleTextView"`.