# padding to ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, actionbardrawertoggle

I want to keep the ActionBarDrawerToggle icon(hamburger) to the edge of the screen.

But by default it gives some space from the edge.[image]

How to keeps the icon to the side of edge(basically no space).

Comment: Have you tried set padding?

Comment: Honestly, that's going to look pretty ugly if you do that. However, if you _really_ want to, it is possible to get a reference to that `ImageButton`. With that, you could then change its left padding, x-coordinate, etc. Alternatively, you could create your own toggle in a `Toolbar`, and set it up however you want.

Comment: Hi Mike, Yes I understood it may looks ugly, but that's the requirement. Is it possible to get reference of the ActionBarDrawerToggle icon resource?

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but ...

Actually Mike answered already similar question here [Get reference to drawer toggle in support actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279953/get-reference-to-drawer-toggle-in-support-actionbar/28280347#28280347)

I just reused his code. After you added the ActionBarDrawerToggle and called syncState() on it

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(...);

//Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

//calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

you can iterate through children of the toolbar and then ...

```
for (int i = 0; i < toolbar.getChildCount(); i++) {
    if(toolbar.getChildAt(i) instanceof ImageButton) {
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) toolbar.getChildAt(i);
        imageButton.setPadding(50, 100, 50, 50);
    }
}
```

Hopefully it helps